# Backand ios SDK

Tags: parse-platform, swift2, xcode7, backand

I am using backand ios SDK for managing backend services to my ios app.step 1 is to add this

```
Parse.setBackandAppName(appName: String, andSignupToken: String)
```

I want to know from where do i get this signUpToken. Actually I was taking the signUpToken from their website from social keys but it gives me this error in console of xcode. It says that invalid or expired token but I have set the token expiry time to a month.

> 2016-03-05 20:39:34.800 backandDemo[644:11115] You are running Parse SDK for Backand! (v0.1.0)
>
> 2016-03-05 20:39:38.624 backandDemo[644:11178] [Error]: {"Message":"invalid or expired token"} (Code: 1, Version: 0.1.0)
> Error : Optional(Error Domain=Parse Code=1 "{"Message":"invalid or expired token"}" UserInfo={error={"Message":"invalid or expired token"}, NSLocalizedDescription={"Message":"invalid or expired token"}, code=1}) Optional([error: {"Message":"invalid or expired token"}, NSLocalizedDescription: {"Message":"invalid or expired token"}, code: 1])

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The signup token user5744323 got from the Backand website social keys was fine. This error is about not having a valid session token and the reason for that is that you have to use PFUser to sign-in or sign-up before you can do pretty much anything at all.